# Protecting against record ID manipulation

Tags: php, database, security

How do you prevent a malicious user from changing URL or form data, specifically a record ID. For example:

http://example.com/deleteproduct.php?id=34

The user could change the ID value from 34 to say 69 and in doing so delete a record belonging to another customer. I guess the obvious protection is to validate the ID before performing the delete to make sure the user has access to that record but is there perhaps another approach that is consider better practice? The downside of validating the ID requires more database queries which would be great to avoid.

Comment: Try to generate random unique id along with primary key. Something like `sdfjh484957934ueirt`.

Comment: You can never be too careful with your data, especially when changing it. Validate everything before you do.

Comment: I would patently avoid query strings for such reasons. In addition, I would use what @Mr.Engineer and Robbie said above. Make sure the ID belongs to the user in question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard:  a malicious user can post a request nearly as easy as modifying a query string.

Comment: That is why I added the additional caveats @BradKent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the obvious protection is to validate the ID before performing the delete to make sure the user has access to that record.

This is the only way to ensure that your user has access to delete these rows.

> The downside of validating the ID requires more database queries which would be great to avoid.

Not necessarily. You can simply check when you're deleting to only delete rows that belong to your user.

For example, assuming your table structure looks similar to:

```
users
-----
id | username
1  | Dave
2  | John

products
-----
id | name | user_owner
1  | Milk | 1
2  | Cake | 2
```

So if Dave visited deleteproduct.php?id=2, the following query would execute:

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE id = 2 AND user_owner = 1;
```

It wouldn't delete anything, and [`$mysqli->affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) would return zero.

When affected rows is zero it means that the product ID was invalid or the product didn't belong to the user, **either way**: you would display a message telling the user that the product id is invalid.

Comment: This logic applies in other places too. For example, if you want to register someone, and check if their username hasn't been taken. Instead of doing two queries (one to select and one to insert). Simply put a unique constraint on the username column and catch any errors with PHP. If `$mysqli->error` is not empty, then the user has been taken already. This a) avoids two queries (saves time), and b) prevents any racing conditions for occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have authorization to delete items?  If so, does it matter?
If it's per-record authorization... just check if they have authorization for the requested id.  Long answer short:  check if they're authorized and never trust user input.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to just keep that as the bottom line: never trust user input

Answer (score 0):

What you said is very dangerous.

### Security

In the first place you need to protect data and make it only available for the selected users. Please create or finetune your access list with roles and permissions.

- Show only links/buttons for elements that may be accessed by the (logged in) user
- Check before access the elements by the (logged in) user the permissions (and role). Not only the action, but also the data
- Authentication (user logged in or not?), authorization (has the user the right permissions to access the (data) element?)

In the second place, it's not a right approach to use internal id's public.

It's always good to hide your internal id's, because it makes your application more safe.

## Data Access

You have to access your data. The most simple idea is checking it in your query, like so:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 34 AND user_id = 1 // Delete only if id = 34 and user is 1
```

Do you understand the idea?

## Internal Id's

You can encode your id's by using existing algorithms. Decoding is only possible with your secret key. There are many solutions and packages.

> Hashids is a small open-source library that generates short, unique, non-sequential ids from numbers. (http://hashids.org/php/)

Comment: Appreciate your input, my project does have user permissions, so a user can only delete a record if they have permission to do so. The problem comes in with the communication of the record ID, it should not be possible to manipulate this value. By it's own admission Hashids is not a strong encryption system and can be broken with a brute force attack. I originally implemented a 32 character hash system that is secure, but it bloats the json data immensely. My question is the start of an evaluation of the whole architecture and what alternative system should be employed.

Comment: Yes, it's right. But it's more secure than using internal id's. Further, I've added a more detailed answer about data access from your query. Let me know if you understand.

Comment: Understood. Two things came out of this: a) I broke the rules by not adding the additional constraint which would ensure that a manipulated ID could not get used and b) the encryption of the ID is not the primary line of defense, the validation is. With that in mind I'm going back to consider Hashids, it makes my code change easier to implement and dissuades ID manipulation by presenting the user with a data value that is not obvious. Thanks again for the input.